# Is the set $A = [0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ countable or not?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Is the set $A = [0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ countable or not?

What I am thinking is $A$ consist of irrational numbers in the interval $[0,1]$ hence it is subset of irrational numbers. As set of irrational numbers is uncountable so I think set $A$ is also uncountable.

Comment: not every subset of irrational numbers is uncountable, but if $A$ and $\mathbb Q$ were both countable then so would be $A\cup \mathbb Q$ and therefore $[0,1]\subset A\cup \mathbb Q$

Comment: $\varnothing$ is also a subset of the irrational numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is uncountable, but not for that reason. For instance, $\left\{\sqrt2+n\,\middle|\, n\in\Bbb N\right\}$ is also a set of irrational numbers, but it is countable.

However, if $[0,1]\setminus\Bbb Q$ was countable, then, since $\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]$ is countable, $[0,1]$ would be countable too, since it's the union of them.

Comment: technically, $[0,1]$ is *contained* in the union of $A$ and $\mathbb Q$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

All countable set of $R$ have Lebesgue measure equal to $0$.
So Lebesgue measure of $[0, 1] - \mathbb{Q}$ is $1$.
Eventually by contraposition, $[0, 1] - \mathbb{Q}$ is uncoutable.

Answer (score 2):

What you are thinking does not work.

For example, $\{n\pi\mid n\in\mathbb N\setminus\{0\}\}$ is a subset of irrational numbers but countable.

Here's an argument that works.  If $A$ were countable, then, since $\mathbb Q$ is countable,

$A\cup \mathbb Q$ would be countable,

and therefore $[0,1]$, which is a subset of $A\cup \mathbb Q$, would be countable,

and that is a contradiction.